# Which python library can I use for creating a simple GUI which should update based on requirement?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a facial recognition attendance system using python on a Raspberry Pi. When each person is detected in the frame, I want a beautiful GUI which should display the name of the detected person along with a good morning message and so on. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Seeking recommendations for tools or libraries is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using python? I never succeeded to make something beautiful with PyQt or Tkinter (maybe you too).

You can use a webserveur using, for example, flask and make it beautifull with angular or simple html/CSS code.

Or you can also try Kivy which is quite nice to see and easy to code :

https://kivy.org/#home

here are some examples:

https://kivy.org/#gallery

it's really easy to learn and to use.

Comment: Will Tkinter update the names quick and work smooth on the raspberry pi? A simple design is enough. Doesn't need to be stunning.

Comment: Tkinter will run faster than PyQt and kivy for sure. But I already used Kivy on a raspberry pi zero W and I didn't had any "lag" troubles too. But for your really simple purpose I think that you can use what you want to : Tkinter is a bit hard to use (and not pretty). PyQt (with QTDesigner) is a bit easier but not pretty. Kivy is simple and quite nice to see but you need to learn a new "langage" .

Comment: I would argue that tkinter is increadibly _easy_ to use - far easier than most UI toolkits.